# Logback 1.7.1, JEE7 - insertFromJNDI fails to retrieve appName

Tags: java, jndi, logback, java-ee-7, payara

I'm trying to setup logging per deployed application (war) on Payara 4.1 using the following statement in my logback.xml configuration.

```
<insertFromJNDI env-entry-name="java:app/AppName" as="appName"/>
<contextName>${appName}</contextName>
```

I get from logback during startup this message:

```
 INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[appName_IS_UNDEFINED]
```

and the context is not set to the correct valeu (e.g. myApplicationName)
but if I do this on a random EJB:

```
@Resource(lookup = "java:app/AppName")
private String appName;
```

I get the expected value. I am suspecting that the Logback configuration tries to retrieve the value before it is set by the container. It is not specifically set so it defaults to the name specified during deployment. Is there a way to get Logback to retrieve it AFTER it was initialized correctly?

Answer (score 1):

ok, I found the error. had **appName** instead of **AppName** in logback config.

```
<insertFromJNDI env-entry-name="java:app/appName" as="appName"/>
<contextName>${appName}</contextName>
```

so simple, but since I over read it several times I hope this will help s.o. to find a similar error. BTW logback is not adding anything (e.g. java:env) to the submitted env-entry-name.

Comment: one word of caution. I have one component that uses `@Startup` for some bootstrapping and I don't get that one to define the logback context correctly via JNDI.

Comment: even before that a `@DataSourceDefinition(name="java:global/MyApp/MyDataSource` is initializing the first logger which tires to retrieve the non existing AppName via JNDI then.